# How can I Accept only letter, number, comma (,) and dot (.) using php

Tags: php, regex

I want to accept only letter, number, comma and dot using following regular expression. If i use `$string`it's saying invalid data but If i use `$string2` it's saying valid data.

1) Why `$string` is not accepting as valid data ? anything I'm missing ?

2) If i accept comma then how can I escape it ? Using mysqli_real_escape_string ? If so then it's showing backslash when I showing it from Db.  Please help. Thank You.

```
$string = "I m a good boy";
$string2 = "Imagoodboy";

if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $string) == 0)
    echo "Invalid data";
else
    echo "Valid data";
```

Comment: I think you may create a new question for the 2), with more details on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `.` in your character class and **reverse** your if condition checks:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/', $string))
    echo "valid data";
else
    echo "InValid data";
```

Also `$string` has spaces also and space is not in your allowed character list that's why it is failing. If you want to include spaces also make regex as:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+$/
```

Comment: using your code it's showing my Invalid data for `$string`

Comment: Great. If I want to accept comma then is it ok ? `/^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]+$/` and if I accept this comma then is it dangerous for database input ?

Comment: Yes for comma regex would be: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]+$/` and you can store comma in database as well, nothing wrong in it.

Comment: Sorry it's not a comma it's ` ' ` e.g -> I'm

Comment: ok then it would be: `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9. ']+$/", $string)` and that can also be stored in database.

Answer (score 1):

First String contain whitespace. According to your regular expression space is not valid.To validate $string you have to make valid whitespace in your regular expression.

Try this :

```
preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9., ]/",$string);
                          ^
                        Space
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from spaces in your $string.

add a space in your capturing group

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+$/", $string) == 0)
    echo "Invalid data";
else
    echo "Valid data";
```

and it should work fine

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rC9rD3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space and `.`, try it:

```
if(preg_match("/^[\d\w\s\.]+$/", $string) == 0)
    echo "Invalid data";
else
    echo "Valid data";
```